# Nexus GraphQL Prisma events field

Tags: graphql, nexus, prisma

For Nexus, I have a JSON field defined in a prisma model (`events Json`) and I want to make a `graphql` mutation to create an instance of that model. However, I do not know what to provide in the `events` field:

```json
args: {
  events: ????,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
args: {
  events: arg({ type: 'Json' })
}
```